# Gaussian distributed magnetic fields

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, statistics

I'm currently reproducing the results of a paper

( https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.96.176804

and old arxiv link https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0507680 )

They measure the current through a double quantum dot for different configurations of an effective nuclear magnetic field representing the hyperfine interaction, and under an external magnetic field $B_0$ along the spin quantization axis (chosen to be z).

The effective nuclear magnetic fields have a Gaussian distribution $\langle \langle (\textbf{B}_{L,R}^N)^2 \rangle \rangle = B_N^2$

They encounter stopping points for the current at $B_0 \approx B_N$ , that from what I can gather correspond to $B_s \perp B_a$ with $B_a=0.5(\textbf{B}_{L} - \textbf{B}_{R})$ and $B_s=0.5(\textbf{B}_{L} + \textbf{B}_{R}) + B_{0}^z$

Now I can't seem to understand where that result comes from. 
If I solve $B_a · B_s = 0$ for $B_0$, what I obtain is:

$B_0=\frac{1}{2} \frac{(|\textbf{B}_{R}|^2-|\textbf{B}_{L}|^2)}{B_{L}^z-B_{R}^z}$

I am not sure if I'm missing something crucial, or if that previous result I obtained leads to $B_0 \approx B_N$ when averaged over many configurations, but I do not know how to mathematically prove that if that's the case.

If anyone could help me and explain to me where that result for the stopping points of the current comes from it'd be incredibly appreciated, since I'm stuck here and I need to understand this to continue working.